# how to fix this problem after installed webmin?

Tags: webmin

[[image]][[image: [1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CiKc.png)

After install complete squid server, I install webmin. but when start webmin on browser, i meet this problem. How can I fix this?

Comment: how can i fix this? anybody help me please

Answer (score 1):

Webmin defaults to "https". Since you haven't set a ssl certificate yet, just click on [Advanced] and click on allow connecting to this site. If you want to secure webmin later, you need a ssl certificate.